# Clipping line with overlaying line in QGIS

Tags: qgis, line, clip, merge, overlapping-features

I have two layers of line which overlap as seen in the picture.
I would like to cut out the first picture with the other as an overlap and then merge them together to get one single layer.

Or is there another way to do this easier?

[image]

[image]

Comment: There are always multiple ways to do something, but "easier" will depend on your familiarity with things like python, virtual layers, etc. Can you share a bit more about the two input datasets, like their source and format? "Overlap" between two line layers is likely to be just a series of points unless the overlapping areas are absolutely identical.

Comment: I am new to GIS so don't know too much. The data is shp files. The overlaping is indentical. 
Yesterday I did this, copying the whole data set from the green layer, past int in to the pink layer and then used Delete duplicate geometries. They also hve identical attribute fields

Comment: You can use `merge vector layers`, then run `delete duplicate geometries` and then you'll have to do some work with `coalesce` using the field calculator.